# Subsets of groups containing identity and inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, groupoids

Let $G$ be a (finite) group, containing a subset $H$. We suppose that $H$ contains the identity and that it is closed under taking inverses.

What are some of the algebraic properties of subgroups that are satisfied also by such a subset? Does the fact that $H$ is contained in $G$ give $H$ any additional property?
What if $H$ is closed under taking powers?

I am particularly interested in what are the orders of the elements of $H$ and if there might be some relation with $|H|$, maybe something like a weaker version of Lagrange's or Cauchy's theorem...

Comment: I have never seen a definition of groupoid that would include these subsets. What definition are you using?

Comment: A groupoid is a set $\displaystyle G$ with a unary operation $\displaystyle {}^{-1}:G\to G,$ and a partial function $\displaystyle *:G\times G\rightharpoonup G$. In this case the inverse and the partial function are the inverse and multiplication of $G$. $H$ is not necessarily closed by the second.

Comment: @user404944: The definition of a groupoid requires much more than that, though.  There must be "objects" such that every element has a domain and codomain object and $*$ respects these in the usual way.

Comment: That's the algebraic definition that wikipedia gives...

Comment: I edited the questions anyways, so that the definition doesn't pose any problem, my question was not about groupoids but about a special kind of subsets of a group

Comment: There is no relation between $|H|$ and orders of elements of $H$. Let $a,b$ be any two positive integers, $b \geq 3$. Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/(b-2)\mathbb{Z}$. Let $H$ consist of a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}$ together with its inverse, together with all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/(b-2)\mathbb{Z}$. Now $|H|=b$ and $H$ contains elements of order $a$. (Modify appropriately if $a \leq 2$.)